# How can I keep a randomized value of a variable constant in a while loop when certain conditions occur?

Tags: c#, random, while-loop

I tried to make an basic number-guessing game. However I couldn't find the way that I keep the randomized number constant in order to give clues to user to increase or decrease his/her guess.This is so easy for you but  I need your valuable and useful perspectives. PS: Yeah I am a beginner.

```
 while (true)
 {
     Random rd = new Random();

     Console.WriteLine("guess a number 0-10");

     guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     comp = rd.Next(10);

     if (guess == comp)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("congratz!! u won!!");
         Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
         break;
     }
     // Those are the conditions for directing user.I couldn't   implement it.

     //else if (guess > comp)
     //    Console.WriteLine("your guess is greater than my number, yow!");
     //else if (guess < comp)
     //    Console.WriteLine("your guess is lower than my number, yow!");


     Console.WriteLine("loser!!" + "My number was:" + comp);
 }
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: The user guess every time a new number .. How can you give a clue on this? you want to give to user another option to guess again?

Comment: First, declare and initialize the `Random` instance before the loop, otherwise you will always generate the same number if the loop executes very quickly.

Comment: Start with setting comp value before the loop.

Comment: ok well done. Thank you for your comments :)

Comment: As you're a beginner, I'd suggest you look at variable scope. This will help you answer questions like this yourself going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment, declare and initialize the `Random` instance before the loop, otherwise you will always generate the same number if the loop executes very quickly. That may not be an issue here because `Console.ReadLine()` stops execution but is important to know anyway.

If you want a number between 0 and 10 you have to use `rd.Next(11)` since the max value is exclusive. Use `int.TryParse` to prevent an exception if the user enters an invalid integer.

Then you could use a `for-loop` to ask the user only n-times and to give clues.

```
int numTries = 3;
Random rd = new Random();
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("guess a number 0-10");
    int number = rd.Next(11); // 0-10
    for (int currentTry = 1; currentTry <= numTries; currentTry++)
    {
        int guess;
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().Trim(), out guess))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer between 0 and 10!");
            continue;  // next try
        }
        if (guess == number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("congratz!! u won!!");
            break;  // breaks for-loop
        }
        else if(currentTry == numTries)  // last try
            Console.WriteLine("loser!!" + "My number was: " + number);
        else if (guess < number)
            Console.WriteLine("your guess is lower than my number, yow!");
        else if (guess > number)
            Console.WriteLine("your guess is greater than my number, yow!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to go like this :

```
Random rd = new Random();
int comp = rd.Next(10); // Store you random number before the loop
int guess = 0;
int trylimit = 3;
int round = 0;

while (round < trylimit)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("guess a number 0-10");

        guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if (guess == comp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("congratz!! u won!!");
                Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
                break;
            }
        else if (guess > comp)
            Console.WriteLine("your guess is greater than my number, yow!");
        else if (guess < comp)
            Console.WriteLine("your guess is lower than my number, yow!");

            round++;
    }
Console.WriteLine("loser!!" + "My number was:" + comp + "\n");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Like Tim Schmelter said in his comment, you need to declare and initialize the `random` before the `while loop` or it might change everytime you enter the loop.

Comment: This doesn't take into account that OP wants to give clues to user. _"give clues to user to increase or decrease his/her guess"_ It always stops after the first try and tells the number which makes the next guess pointless.

Comment: Which is why I edited it, even though it kind of look like the others post now.

Answer (score 1):

you can ask the user for n times before declaring him loser. Of course I did not checked for correct user input; beware of non-numerical user inputs!

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int comp = rnd.Next(10);
int guess;
int numberofGuesses = 3;
int counter = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("guess a number 0-10");
        do
        {
            guess = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (guess == comp)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("congratz!! u won!!");
                Console.WriteLine("press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (guess > comp)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your guess is greater than my number, yow!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("your guess is lower than my number, yow!");
                }
                if(counter!=numberofGuesses - 1)
                    Console.WriteLine("Guess again!");
                counter++;
            }
        } while (counter < numberofGuesses);


        Console.WriteLine("loser!!" + "My number was:" + comp);
        Console.ReadKey();
        return;
    }
```